# GL VertexBuffer INVALID OPERATION

Tags: java, opengl

I created a VBO:

`GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, VBO, 0);
   GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
   GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferVertexData.capacity() * 4, 
   BufferVertexData, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

and all it's ok...
but then, when i call

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
```

I get the error 1282: INVALID OPERATION
If I call
    `GLES20.glIsBuffer(VBO[0]);` 
returns true...

But still I can't draw anything....

Comment: Sorry about checking for the obvious, but did you verify that `glGetError()` returns no error **before** the `glBindBuffer()` call? At least in ES 2.0, INVALID_OPERATION is not documented as a possible error from `glBindBuffer()`.

Comment: Thanks,  in fact I realized the error was caused by called GLES20.glUnifrom1f to a sampler in the fragment shader ;)